# Server response "Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I searched for all of the similar posts on Stackoverflow and other websites trying to find the solution.

I'm still at the start of the project, the WildFly server runs, but when I send a GET request using Postman to the endpoint that is supposed to create a new row in the database, I get the response:
"Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]".

At the time I send the request the server console logs the following:
`15:49:47,123 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (default task-1) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default] 15:49:47,129 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (default task-1) HHH10005002: No explicit CDI BeanManager reference was passed to Hibernate, but CDI is available on the Hibernate ClassLoader. 15:49:47,134 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-1) HHH10001002: Using built-in connection pool (not intended for production use)`

The endpoint code is as follows:

```
@Path("/lead")
public class LeadResource {
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("/test")
public void getLeads() {

    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

    try{
        transaction.begin();

        LeadsEntity leadsEntity = new LeadsEntity();
        leadsEntity.setLeadId(5);
        leadsEntity.setFirstName("Test");
        leadsEntity.setLastName("Tester");
        leadsEntity.setAddress("Test street 2");
        leadsEntity.setAge(33);

        entityManager.persist(leadsEntity);
        transaction.commit();
    }finally {
        if(transaction.isActive()){
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}

@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("/hello-world")
public String getHello() {

    return "Hello World!";
}
}
```

In this segment the /hello-world endpoint works fine and it returns "Hello World!" to Postman, but the /test endpoint that is supposed to enter a row into the database doesn't.

Class LeadsEntity.java was generated by hibernate by right clicking in the Persistence window -> Generate Persistence Mapping -> By database schema and selecting my database.
Class LeadsEntity.java code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "leads", schema = "zadatakdb")
public class LeadsEntity {
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
@Column(name = "lead_id")
private int leadId;
@Basic
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Basic
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Basic
@Column(name = "age")
private int age;
@Basic
@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

public int getLeadId() {
    return leadId;
}

public void setLeadId(int leadId) {
    this.leadId = leadId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    LeadsEntity that = (LeadsEntity) o;

    if (leadId != that.leadId) return false;
    if (age != that.age) return false;
    if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(that.firstName) : that.firstName != null) return false;
    if (lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(that.lastName) : that.lastName != null) return false;
    if (address != null ? !address.equals(that.address) : that.address != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = leadId;
    result = 31 * result + (firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + age;
    result = 31 * result + (address != null ? address.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
}
```

And the last file persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

```
    <class>entity.LeadsEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zadatakdb"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have checked the database name, username and password with test connection, the mysql connector is in place, I have checked everything and I'm not sure what the problem is still...

Thanks to anyone that tries to help!

Answer (score 0):

I'll repost my answer from Zulip here since I just found your post: [https://hibernate.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/132096-hibernate-user/topic/.E2.9C.94.20Hibernate.20doesn't.20connect.20to.20Database](https://hibernate.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/132096-hibernate-user/topic/.E2.9C.94.20Hibernate.20doesn%27t.20connect.20to.20Database)

If you use Wildfly, you should rather use a datasource and configure the datasource name in the persistence.xml

See http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-datasource/configuring-a-datasource-with-postgresql-and-jboss-wildfly/ for example